# Curl request for javascript form(header request included)

Tags: javascript, forms, cookies, curl, content-type

I get 405 Method Not Allowed from the below commands:

```
curl -H "Accept: Accept=text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST --data "password=456&press=Submit" http://192.168.0.135

curl -A "User-Agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0" -H "Content-Type: X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" --data "password=456&press=Submit" http://192.168.0.135
```

I am trying to curl a javascript form, here is the header and response from tamper data:

```
GET http://192.168.0.135/auth.htm?t=Mon,%2002%20Sep%202013%2008:42:14%20GMT Load Flags[LOAD_BACKGROUND  ] Content Size[-1] Mime Type[text/html]
   Request Headers:
      Host[192.168.0.135]
      User-Agent[Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0]
      Accept[*/*]
      Accept-Language[en-US,en;q=0.5]
      Accept-Encoding[gzip, deflate]
      DNT[1]
      X-Requested-With[XMLHttpRequest]
      Authorization[Basic UG9seWNvbTo0NTY=]
      Referer[http://192.168.0.135/login.htm]
      Connection[keep-alive]
   Response Headers:
      Server[Polycom SoundPoint IP Telephone HTTPd]
      Date[WED, 21 AUG 2013 04:21:42 GMT]
      Connection[keep-alive]
      Transfer-Encoding[chunked]
      Content-Type[text/html]
```

Comment: and did you check what the "Polycom SoundPoint IP Telephone HTTPd" API  is for authenticated form data?

Comment: Not sure if this has anything useful: Web Server <httpd/>
The phone contains a local web server for user and administrator features. 
This can be disabled for applications where it is not needed or where it poses 
a security threat. *The web server supports both basic and digest 
authentication.* The authentication user name and password are not 
configurable for this release.

Comment: Also from web dev guide: *There is XML API support for applications on the SoundPoint IP* but this may be related to the microbrowser on the phone which can display messages ect.